# SQL Server Log info for DELETE row(s) on a table

Tags: sql-server, logging

Is there any way to know:

1. client username
2. client ip address
3. operation timestamp

of a **row delete operation** on some table in Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

MS-SQL comes with some built in logging function for each database running on 
[full recovery models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx) (which is default).

You can try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
WHERE Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
```

Then:

```
SELECT [Transaction SID]
FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE [Transaction ID] = @TranID
AND [Operation] = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT'
```

And finally:

```
SELECT * FROM sysusers WHERE [sid] = @SID
```

---

[Check out this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/) for further reading and additional abilities.

---

**If this doesn't work** - This means MS-SQL does not have the logging functions, and you would have to create them.

Luckily, It's simple enough - just follow [these instructions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3090/how-to-find-user-who-ran-drop-or-delete-statements-on-your-sql-server-objects/).

Comment: this also means ,the user should in full recovery model,for him to query TLOG